# if dropdownlist autopostback property true then select any value it's automatic select index 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i have 3 dropdownlist when i select first dropdown fill 2nd and 3rd when i select 3rd dropdown any value it's automatic select index 1 both dropdown 2nd and 3rd. i want do some work on 3rd dropdown selected index change. here is my aspx code

```
body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">select</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</form>
```

and my cs code is

```
HotelBAL objhotel = new HotelBAL();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //objhotel.searchHotelRoomType(DropDownList1, "1");

    }
}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    objhotel.searchHotelOccupancy(DropDownList2, id);
    objhotel.searchHotelMealPlan(DropDownList3, id);
}
protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you are filling you dropdown list in

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
          //LoadDropdownListHere();
    }
```

Comment: I m not filling any dropdown on page load.

Comment: Please check that method that fill the dropdown may call every time on postback and filling the dropdown again and setting the selected values to first item.

Comment: yes it's method problem when i change my method it's work properly in my method i m using connect mood now i go with disconnected now it's working properly thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Add default value in the drop down. and in the event

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        if(!id.Equals("select"))
         {
           objhotel.searchHotelOccupancy(DropDownList2, id);
           objhotel.searchHotelMealPlan(DropDownList3, id);
         }
    }
```

Try this..

Comment: it's not working. same problm when i select any  value of dropdownlist3 then dropdownlist2 and dropdownlist2 select first value auotomatically